# UICollectionView Scroll issue on reload item or other view update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, user-interaction

I have a banner view, collection view, bottom view in my view controller. I load the data for all the views from api responses. Even each collection view cell has its own apis and response to update. So to update the data i reload collection view cells on corresponding response and the same for banner and bottom views. In result of so many reloads/view updates my collection view is not scrolling smoothly. Could anyone suggest a good way to get data from apis and load into collection view and other views without affecting user interaction.

Comment: where is the code

Comment: I hope you are fetching data from the API on a background thread atleast?

Comment: @Rikh yes I'm fetching data on background thread

Comment: @PatelJigar sorry as it was too complex and lengthy i didnt add the code in question. I will try to create a mock code and update the question

Comment: Have you used the time profiler to understand which methods are taking the longest time and tried to optimise them? Are you loading the data to your datasource on a background queue and then updating your UI on the main queue? I would look at the free WWDC videos from Apple for the last three years - there are multiple videos which discuss how to optimise your app to make it responsive.

Comment: @RoboticCat yes I'm loading data on background queue. I haven't tried profiler yet. I will check that